# USB sound card doesn't work properly in Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: usb, 16.04, soundcard, ubuntu-mate, external-soundcard

I have a problem with my e-mu 0202 usb sound card. I've been using ubuntu 15.04 15.10 and 16.04 and it works just fine in there. But not in ubuntu mate 16.04

The problem is my usb card just shuts down for some reason. For example it's off by default when i boot. I can switch it on in sound settings and it works and produces sound. But if i try to use any application it just powers off.

Any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've ran into the exact same problem. I am currently using pulseaudio volume control (pavucontrol) as a workaround.

Install PulseAudio Volume Control from terminal: (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Once it's installed, run the program:

```
pavucontrol
```

You will find the emu sound card listed as an output device. If not, try reconnecting the device.

Set the profile of the sound devices you don't use to off in the configuration tab and check that the E-mu card is set to Analogue Stereo Duplex.

As long as I keep the pulseaudio volume control running my external sound card works flawlessly.

For now, I just added PulseAudio Volume Control to my startup applications list.

The easiest way to do this is to start the Startup Applications application (System -> Preferences -> Personal -> Startup Applications) and drag-and-drop PulseAudio Volume Control (Applications -> Sound and Video -> PulseAudio Volume Control ) into the Startup Applications window.

If I find a more elegant solution, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda solved problem with having to have pavucontrol always open. All you need to do is uncomment line `# load-module module-suspend-on-idle` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`